# Thunderbird attachments missing

Tags: windows-xp, email, thunderbird, imap, attachments

I'm running Thunderbird 8 on Windows XP with no add-ons. I'm using an IMAP server. On some of the emails I am getting, there aren't attachments even though I have confirmed that attachments exists on the mail server via webmail.

Any ideas why the emails aren't showing that they have attachments in Thunderbird?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into Tools > Options > Advanced > General, click on Config Editor, then set the `mailnews.display.show_all_body_parts_menu preference` to true.

Now you should be able to activate the menu item View > Message Body As > All Message Parts as needed to access any content as attachment.

Comment: The `Config Editor` is now _(March 2023, v102.8.0)_ under: `Edit` > `Settings` > `General` > `Indexing` > `Config Editor`

Answer (score 1):

+1

Attachments are here and can be seen with view / message source. But they are not shown in the message body.

This bug appeared with Thunderbird 8. I'm using it with an IMAP server, under Windows 7/32.

Not all attachments disappeared. Some are viewable, some others are not. Most of the  non-viewable attachments for me are PDFs located in my fax server public folder.